# Не появляется папка resources после создания maven проекта quickstart

Tags: java

Не появляется папка resources после создания maven проекта quickstart Почему, и как сделать, чтобы появилась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И не должна. Не в каждом проекте есть ресурсы. Просто создайте папку самостоятельно.

Comment: А папку META-INF тоже можно вручную создавать?

Comment: Нет, её обычно генерирует плагин-упаковщик.

Comment: вообще есть для этого архитипы, META-INF только для webapp